# Error in accessing parent scope property in handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, templating, handlebarshelper

I am using a handlebars template with nested `each` and `if` helpers. It looks like this

```
{{each resultSet}}
   ...some html...
   {{each segment}}
       {{if @index}}
            ---some html--
            {{../someParentValue}}
       {{/if}}
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

When I access this `someParentValue` I get this error in the console `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined"`

If I add another level in the path i.e `../../someParentValue` to get to the scope of each resultSet, then I get the error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined"`

I am not sure what could be wrong in this as while inspecting the resultSet, I can see that each item in that result set has the property that I am trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

New in Handlebars 3.0, it's possible to receive named parameters from supporting helpers.

```
{{each resultSet as |rs}}
   ...some html...
   {{each segment as |seg}}
       {{if @index}}
            ---some html--
            {{rs.someResultSetProperty}}
       {{/if}}
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Hope this helps.